# Need a help in understanding the proof of linear independence of the function $\chi _{\tau_{k}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, induction, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The question is (b) in the following pictures:

[image] 
[image]

The answer for (b) is given in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

But it is not clear for me:
1- why in the forth line in the answer the author put $\frac{\tau_{1}}{2}$ instead of t? could anyone clarify this for me please?

2-Also why in the sixth line in the answer the author put $\frac{(\tau_{n-1} + \tau_{n})}{2}$ instead of t?could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: That's a matter of taste. Both ways work fine. In fact, any number from $[\tau_{i-1},\tau_i)$ will do.

Comment: But he took the value of $\chi$ in the first case 1 and in the second case 0, and I did not understand why ..... could you clarify this for me please? @SergeiGolovan

Comment: Frankly I do not understand what do you >>>> could u please explain what you said in details? >>>>> thanks in advance @SergeiGolovan

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Ok I am so sorry @GNUSupporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If we put $\tau_{1}$, then $\chi_{\tau_{1}}(\tau_{1})=0$, so from $\alpha_{1}\chi_{\tau_{1}}(\tau_{1})=0$, we cannot conclusively say that $\alpha_{1}=0$. If we put $\tau_{1}/2$, then $\chi_{\tau_{1}}(\tau_{1}/2)=1$, so $\alpha_{1}=0$.

2) The trick is similar to the first one. If we put $\tau_{n}$, then $\chi_{\tau_{n}}(\tau_{n})=0$, once again nothing can be said to $\alpha_{n}$. With $0<\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}<\tau_{n}$ (remember that $0<\tau_{n-1}<\tau_{n}$), then $\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=1$. And luckily, since $0<\tau_{1}<\cdots<\tau_{n-1}$, we have $\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}>\tau_{k}$ for all $k=1,...,n-1$, then $\chi_{k}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=0$ for all such $k$, so those terms $\alpha_{k}\chi_{\tau_{k}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=0$ and the only term left in $\alpha_{1}\chi_{\tau_{1}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)$ is $\alpha_{n}\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)$, so from $\alpha_{1}\chi_{\tau_{1}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)+\cdots+\alpha_{n}\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=0$, then we conclude that $\alpha_{n}\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=0$, with the result that $\chi_{\tau_{n}}\left(\dfrac{\tau_{n-1}+\tau_{n}}{2}\right)=1$, then $\alpha_{n}=0$. So we get $\alpha_{1}\chi_{\tau_{1}}\left(t\right)+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}\chi_{\tau_{n-1}}\left(t\right)=0$, and induction hypothesis implies that $\alpha_{1}=\cdots=\alpha_{n-1}=0$.